# Setting up protected routes in React with react-router-6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, protected

I am using keycloak for my React + Typescript app and I need to setup ProtectedRoutes so that certain paths can only be accessed when the user has logged in. I have the keycloak part working but for some reason, I am unable to pass custom props to the components and the `props` in the Component is empty.

**My react-router-dom version is 6.3.0**

Following is what I am trying

```
function ProtectedRoute({ children, ...rest }: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak()
    if (!keycloak?.authenticated) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }
    return children ;
}
```

**Usage**

```
const global = {
    isSomething: isSomethingSelected,
    setSomethingSelected: setsomethingSelected
}

<Routes>
                  
    <Route path='/books' element={<ProtectedRoute global={global}><Books /></ProtectedRoute>}/>

</Routes
```

**Component**

```
export default function Books(props: any) {
    const { global } = props;
  console.log(global); // props is empty
}
```

Comment: The `Books` component isn't passed any props, so OFC `props.global` is undefined. Do you need `<Books global={global} />`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact you're passing the props to `ProtectedRoute` and not to `Books` component.

```
<Route path='/books' element={<ProtectedRoute><Books global={global} /></ProtectedRoute>}/>
```

On the other hand, I would make it a little different, if you want the suggestion.

```
function ProtectedRoute(props: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

  if (!keycloak?.authenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <Route {...props} />
  );
}
```

```
const global = {
  isSomething: isSomethingSelected,
  setSomethingSelected: setsomethingSelected
}

<Routes>        
  <ProtectedRoute path="/books" element={<Books global={global} />}/>

</Routes
```